# Apache 2.4 - allow access from same IP and from curl Request

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I want to provide access to requests from the same server that apache is running on and to curl requests, but this section does not work, neither the first nor the second match. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <LocationMatch "^/myLocation">
   <If "%{HTTP_REFERER} == 'localhost'">
     Require all granted
   </If>
   <ElseIf "%{USER_AGENT} =~ /curl/ >
     Require all granted
   </ElseIf>
   <Else>
     Require all denied
   </Else>  
 </LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you shouldn't base access controls on either the `HTTP_REFERER` header   nor the `USER_AGENT` header ; both are set by the site visitor and can't be trusted, any  (malicious) user can manipulate those.

Second, to provide access to requests from the same server, that depends a bit on how you make them.

- Are you making requests to `http://localhost/myLocation` - then requests will also originate from localhost you can base access controls on the 127.0.0.1 and/or [::1] IP-address.
- Are your making requests to the external IP i.e. `http://www.example.com/myLocation` then you need to add your external IP-address.

Rather than an if-then-else construction Apache httpd offers the [`RequireAny`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany) directive to achieve what you want:

```
<Location /myLocation>
   <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require expr %{HTTP_REFERER} == 'localhost'
       Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /curl/
   </RequireAny> 
</Location>
```

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be low-level security, rather to be safe from ambitious users in the intranet than to russian hackers.